# Including ejs partial with listner button not working; how to fix static?

Tags: html, express, button, static, ejs

I am trying to include a partial on the page with my backend coming later. I want to use an event listener button. It dosent work. I am using express.ejs and node.js with vanilla js.

I am using this for my vanilla js

```
const button = document.getElementById('button')

button.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    const hi = document.createElement(`<%-require('../views/partials/hi.ejs')%>`)
    
    document.appendChild(hi)
})
```

this for my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>hi</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<button id="button">Im a button</button>
    
<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this for my node

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.set('view engine','ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('layout')
})



app.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log('server listening')
})
```

I get this error when i try to use the partial with the button

```
main.js:4 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('<%-require('../views/partials/hi.ejs')%>') is not a valid name.
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:5000/main.js:4:25)
```

this comes from client side....why and how to fix?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. The handler is client side JS, but processed by EJS? Did you look at your rendered JS to see if that worked?

Comment: Define “it worked”. What is the rendered “vanilla JS”? Is it properly JS-escaped?

Comment: the no console log for client side worked , the ejs worked but the button didnt @DaveNewton do you want whole folder

Comment: The console log is in the server code. The issue is with the client code.

Comment: no the server listen is in the server code the button is in the client and not working @DaveNewton

Comment: That’s what I said—the issue is in the client code. But we can’t see how it’s being rendered—and based on the error it’s not being processed on the server side at all, so obviously it won’t work like that. You may be confusing client and server code.